# My 'move_uploaded_file()' does not move my image to my specified folder

Tags: php

```
 <?php
    include("config.php");
    //Get the name of the input type submit
    if(ISSET($_POST['sign_up'])) {
        $username = trim($_POST['user']); 
        $password = trim($_POST['pass']);
        $gender=$_POST['gen'];
        $firstname =($_POST['first']); 
        $lastname = trim($_POST['last']);
        $y=$_POST['y'];
        $m=$_POST['m'];
        $d=$_POST['d'];
        $dob=$y."-".$m."-".$d;
        $imgpath=$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $imgFile = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $tmp_dir = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); 
        $userpic = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;      
        if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
            if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
                $msg_error = "Username already registered!";
            } else {
                if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users
                             values('','$username','".MD5($password)."', '$gender', 
                                    '$dob', '$imgpath', 'guest', 
                                    '$firstname', '$lastname')")
                         or die(mysql_error()); 
                    $uuid=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
                    while ($puid=mysql_fetch_array($uuid)){
                        $pid = $puid['user_id'];
                        mkdir("userImages/$pid");
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "userImages/$pid/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                    }
                    //image uploaded should be moved to my specified 
                    //folder after the code above is executed   

                    $_SESSION['sname']=$_POST['user'];
                    $msg_success = "You are now registered!";
                }
                else{
                    $msg_error = "Invalid image!";
                }
            }
        }else{
            $msg_error = "All fields are required!";
    }
}
?>
```

this is my php code. Can someone help me in figuring out why my       'move_uploaded_file()' is not working?

Comment: stop using the **deprecated `mysql_*`** extension, use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [mysqli_*](http://php.net/mysqli) instead;

Comment: What is your form code?

Comment: <form action = "" method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" id="ima" name="file" accept="image/*"></form>

Comment: Did you enable error reporting for more information,

Answer (score 0):

Check your destination folder permissions. error_get_last could give you some clue to why it doesn't work. Check this [example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php#116451)

```
$targetFile = "userImages/$pid/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFile)) { 
    echo "<P>FILE UPLOADED TO: $target_file</P>"; 
} else { 
    echo "<P>MOVE UPLOADED FILE FAILED!</P>"; 
    print_r(error_get_last()); 
}
```

Comment: I'm actually new in php. Where should I code  'error_get_last' ?

Comment: This should work 

`if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "userImages/$pid/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
      echo "<P>FILE UPLOADED TO: $target_file</P>";
   } else {
      echo "<P>MOVE UPLOADED FILE FAILED!</P>";
      print_r(error_get_last());
   }`

Comment: should a value for $target_file be initialized?

Comment: Yes. Edited my answer to reflect correct bit of code. error_get_last should at least give you some insight to why move doesn't work. You can work on that to implement proper error handling.